# SDL MIX_LOADWAV() crashes on loading some wav files

Tags: c++, sdl

I have a C++ Program that loads wave files. and accepts keystrokes to function as a piano. Recently, I tried changing the wav files from notes from the internet, to live recording notes. The only difference in the files might be that the live recordings are in stereo. in any event, when I give Mix_LoadWAV(a.wav) it returns null [For example, all the live recordings load null].

Is there any limitions to the sdl 1.2 MIX_LOADWAV() I should konw about?

```
bool LoadFiles()
{
    Background = LoadImage("graphics/background.bmp");

    cNote = Mix_LoadWAV("notes/c.wav" );
    csNote = Mix_LoadWAV("notes/cs.wav" );
    dNote = Mix_LoadWAV("notes/d.wav" );
    dsNote = Mix_LoadWAV("notes/ds.wav" );
    eNote = Mix_LoadWAV("notes/e.wav" );
    fNote = Mix_LoadWAV("notes/f.wav" );
    fsNote = Mix_LoadWAV("notes/fs.wav" );
    gNote = Mix_LoadWAV("notes/g.wav" );
    gsNote = Mix_LoadWAV("notes/gs.wav" );
    aNote = Mix_LoadWAV("notes/a.wav" );
    asNote = Mix_LoadWAV("notes/as.wav" );
    bNote = Mix_LoadWAV("notes/b.wav" );
    highCNote = Mix_LoadWAV("notes/highC.wav" );

    if(Background == NULL || cNote == NULL || csNote == NULL || dNote == NULL || dsNote == NULL || eNote == NULL || fNote == NULL || fsNote == NULL || gNote == NULL || gsNote == NULL || aNote == NULL || asNote == NULL || bNote == NULL || highCNote == NULL)
    {
        printf("File load error\n");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: From the SDL docs: https://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/Mix_LoadWAV. So I would  convert it to OGG (or any other of the listed things) and see if it works. In any case, I myself have had bad experience with format support in SDL_mixer, but maybe we both are doing something wrong. The docs aren't very clear about the audio format specifics :/

Comment: Also, I am not sure SDL_mixer is the right thing for what you are trying to do. I'd suggest switching to a more sophisticated audio library (you can try looking [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links/libs), because I'd bet, you will run into other limitations of SDL even after you resolve this issue at hand.

Comment: I just tried Mix_LoadMUS() instead of Mix_LoadWAV() and it seems like it might work. It would seem Mix_LoadWAV isnt for all wav files Mix_LoadMUS seems to open other wavs fine. Its confusing though, I tried finding clear documentation on what the difference between a wav and a wav music file is. I tried making my live recordings into mono chanel wave files, but that didnt help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured out the problem with SDL Mixer's WAV loading function, after much hardship today. I re-recorded some sound effects, and once I replaced them, the game I was working on crashed completely. After some error tracing, I deduced it was Mixer refusing to load the new WAV files, but I could not figure out why.

Then it occurred to me that I had recorded the new sound effects in Audacity, and had saved them as **32-bit signed PCM,** instead of **16-bit PCM.**

[image]

It turns out that **Load_WAV does not support 32-bit signed PCM WAV files**, and will crash if you try to load them. Instead, **you have to convert them to 16-bit signed PCM WAV files**, i.e. using a program like Audacity. Once you do that, it works perfectly.

Hopefully this helps someone out who was as confused as me and OP! As far as I know the documentation never says this limitation anywhere, so I'm sure it has tripped up a lot of people.

*(Other place this was noted: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/136817/how-to-get-sdl2-to-play-32bit-wav-files)*

Comment: I forgot about this post. Back when I was working on this project, I found essentially, this in the SDL documentation. There is a more permissive sound function in SDL, which I ended up using, but off hand I cannot remember what it was.